# Rejected Leave after Verbally accepting

Tags: work-environment, manager, work-life-balance, leave-of-absence

Scenario: Joined with a company last week , I was Interviewed almost 1 month before and offered me a position, before accepting the offer I have mentioned that I need to take a day off within 2 week of joining.
HR accepted that and I accepted their offer.On the date of joining I mentioned the same with HR and My Manager and they verbally accepted it.

I applied for leave through our internal application yesterday and got rejected, with a comment as given below.

> Already too many leaves got approved on x th,so granting further leaves on same date won't be possible.

But I can not come to work on that day, I have something to do very personal. What should be the next step? Consult with HR or go to the manager?

There is a chance that manager might have forgot about verbally accepting my leave application.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Talked with manager , mentioned the importance of that day for me and mentioned about his verbal acceptance.

He said : OK , apply again I will reconsider.

Comment: Unfortunately verbal agreements aren't worth the paper they're written on...

Comment: Yes I know,but I am feeling really bad as I just joined the company.I want some positive advice :) :(

Comment: Have you said that to them, that it's to take care of something very personal?  You don't have to explicitly state what it is, just so they know that you're not applying for some spurious reason.

Comment: I just said 'Personal' ,didn't mention more about it.

Comment: Hopefully it was just standard rejection your boss will address.  You should not need to say "very personal".  "I have to personal matters to attend to that I disclosed prior to accepting the job."  In hind site you should have put that date in your written acceptance.

Comment: Please just ask your manager about these things before writing it up as a question. Voting to close as company-specific as the OP just needed to go through established channels (which we don't know) to figure out whether there even was a problem (there probably isn't).

Comment: Had to VTC - This is company-specific.  However, this came to mind as I read the question:  https://www.socialpsychology.org/reject.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments, it sounds as though while you have said that you need to take the day for personal reasons, you haven't really implied the importance of the task/thing you need to do on that day.

You don't need to explicitly state what it is, but you should take your manager aside and stress that you have to take care of something deeply personal on that day which cannot be deferred to another day.

There is really not much more you can do than to explain the personal significance to your manager.  If they absolutely will not allow you take that day, then you may have to consider options, such as if you really *must* do the thing on that day, or if you would be late/miss work without permission.  But I would hope that if the manager understands how important this is, then they would try a little harder on your behalf.

Answer (score 3):

If necessary, tell management that this is important enough that you'll take an unpaid day off. That both emphasizes that you're serious and gives them a better alternative to your simply not appearing in the office.

Comment: That's great advice!